# How can I run two Skype accounts at same time (windows)?

Tags: user-accounts, skype

I would like to use private skypeid and some company skypeid at same time. I see that some people do this, so I guess it is pretty simple.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1201513/how-to-run-two-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time-in-windows-10/1526646#1526646

Comment: @AttaH. - other question is duplicate (it is from 2017, mine is from 2010)

Comment: I apologize sir, i tried the same solution and it worked for me last week

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new shortcut to Skype.exe. Edit the shortcut by right-clicking the shortcut and choose Properties. Change the `Target` by adding `/secondary` so at the end it looks like this:

```
“C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe” /secondary
```

This should work, another method is by running Skype as a different user. Create a new Windows account for this (with password) and run Skype as the newly created user.

Comment: also you can run 3 or more by adding the /username switch