# How to run two Skype accounts at the same time in Windows-10?

Tags: windows-10, skype

I've just performed the way like below URL to run two Skype accounts.

*https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA829/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time*

Finally I got the error.

> The name "C:\Program Files(x86)\skype\phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
>   specified in the Target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file
>   name are correct.

how can i resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to add space between skype.exe" and /secondary?

Comment: The folder is called `Program Files (x86)`. There is a missing space in the question. Also, Skype may not be installed at this location at all.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, This is simple just add 
"C:\Program Files(x86)\skype\phone\Skype.exe" --secondary

Instead of 
"C:\Program Files(x86)\skype\phone\Skype.exe" /secondary

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut for skype.exe and change the target as (based on x64 or x86)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe" --secondary --datapath "%appdata%\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\profile-xx"

/secondary will not work with new skype and windows 10

For more details check this article

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-at-the-same/c64540e4-20b5-4a78-a039-fd8ab2c59624

Comment: Yes, you are right --secondary not working in windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to property of skype app on Desktop and replace target with **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe" --secondary**

Save and you can open multiple skype by clicking one skype app of Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe" --secondary --datapath "%appdata%\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\profile-xx"

It works on my end.

Comment: why did you copy [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1526646/763386)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help].